# Do use/mention errors actually happen?

Tags: fallacies, use-mention

It is commonplace to see warnings in introductory philosophy texts about not confusing use and mention, but I can't imagine how any reasonably analytical thinker could make such an error, so I've never seen the point of this warning. I occasionally see an internet commenter accusing someone of such confusion, but in every case I've seen, the accusation was obviously wrong, and I've never seen an accuser in such a case make a serious effort to back up his claim.

It should be easy to prove that someone has confused use and mention. In order for a use/mention confusion to occur, the sentence would have to use a term, say X in two different ways, one of which which refers to X as a language token and one of which refers to an instance of whatever X refers too. For example:

```
Induction is a form of inference with three syllables.
```

It is easy to point out that no form of inference has any syllables because syllables are features of words, and forms of inference are not words.

My question is: are there any genuine examples from the history of philosophy where some philosopher has credibly accused another of a use/mention confusion? Or, failing that, are there clear examples of typical arguments that make such an error?

Comment: Those who confuse use and mention do not conveniently use X in two different ways in a single sentence. More commonly, they observe lack of mention of X in some complex discourse and surmise that it is not used there either. Arguing that it is, in fact, used, or "presupposed", may not be easy at all, and is often controversial. Husserl and Wittgenstein make many such arguments, Ayer claimed analytic philosophers use verificationism w/o mentioning it, Azzouni claimed philosophers of mathematics confuse use and mention when declaring diagrammatic proofs non-rigorous, etc.

Comment: Related [What are some non-trivial examples of the use/mention error?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/77520/9148)

Comment: TIL: "A white horse is not a horse"

Comment: @Conifold, I read the entry you linked to, and that's not a use/mention confusion. Use/mention refers to words. It's related to quotation. In that answer what is claimed to be confused is not use and mention of a word but use and mention of a rule.

Comment: Sometimes also philosopher can be sloppy. The well-know Leibniz's dictum regarding identity is: *Eadem sunt quorum unum potest substitui alteri salva veritate*. As noted by contemporary logician Alonzo Church (*Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (1956), page 300, footnote 302): "In this form there is a certain confusion of use and mention: things are identical if the name of one can be substituted for that of the other without loss of truth."